# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._comp

Tags: django, pip

The error:
[image]

My packages:

[image]

The error message says that I don't have this model. However I could successfully install it using `pip` and `pip freeze` shows it.

What is wrong with my install/script?

Answer (score 2):

The version of Markupsafe is problematic.

I downgraded to `Markupsafe==1.1.1` (because I had `2.0.1`) and I don't have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The module is called `markupsafe._compat`. See it at
https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/tree/master/markupsafe in file `_compat.py`. You have a problem in your code, probably copy/paste error.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem. Reinstalling Jinja helped